# How can I keep track of all the packages / dependencies that are installed when I run apt-get for a specific package?

Tags: apt, bash

I am trying to write a script that runs in the background and keeps track of the packages I install manually with the `apt-get` command. For example -

I open up a terminal and run `sudo apt-get install vim` to get the following output :

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
The following extra packages will be installed:
  vim-runtime
Suggested packages:
  ctags vim-doc vim-scripts
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  vim vim-runtime
0 upgraded, 2 newly installed, 0 to remove and 574 not upgraded.
Need to get 5,844 kB of archives.
After this operation, 28.0 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n]
```

... which is effectively installing the `vim` and `vim-runtime` packages on my system. I am trying to write a bash script that keeps 'listening' to the terminal and whenever a `sudo-apt get install` is run, pipe the output to a specific text file.

In the above example, the output to this file, say `apt-specs.txt`, would be -

```
sudo apt-get install vim
installed Packages - vim, vim-runtime
```

Any pointers as to how this can be accomplished?

P.S. If there's any other way to do this viz. refer to a file that already contains this information as part of the install process, instead of constantly tracking the usages of `apt-get install` in the terminal, that would be welcome as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a look at `/var/log/apt/history.log`

Comment: perfect! i knew i was missing out on some information here. thanks a lot! just to pile on to this question,  does information regarding 3rd party repos that I've added maually with `add-apt-repository` get logged anywhere like it is here?